# Create functions indexes MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with [date] index.

[date] column:

```
'2015-01-05'
'2015-01-06'
and etc
```

Can I create new index for function index?
When i am trying to create it I get error, example:

```
create index date_y on table (year(date))
```

If I could we didn't recreate queries for program performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. No, you cannot create an index on an expression in this fashion. However, if you happen to have mysql v5.7.8 or newer, then you can create [generated columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns) and you can create [a secondary index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-secondary-indexes-virtual-columns) on them (secondary index means that a generated column cannot be part of a primary key).

So, create your expression as a generated column and then create an index on it - if you have mysql v5.7.8 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

**One moment, when I have:**

```
   date is created index on tableX
   id is created index on tableX
   id is created index on tableY
```

**My query:**

```
   Select * from tableX as x left outer join tableY as y on x.id=y.id 
    where year(x.date)=2015 and month(x.date)=11
```

**Should I recreate date to:**

```
create index date on tableX (date,id)
```

**or some else?**